# Terminal speed of sphere moving in laminar flow

Tags: fluid-dynamics, flow, viscosity

I am trying to find the terminal speed of a sphere moving horizontally (in the x direction) in laminar flow. There is a pressure gradient in the x direction, with pressure $p_0$ at the inlet and 0 at the outlet and the separation between the inlet and outlet being $L$. From the [Basset-Bousinessq-Oseen equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basset%E2%80%93Boussinesq%E2%80%93Oseen_equation), ignoring terms 3, 4 and 5 on the RHS and the term on the LHS (due to steady state), I obtain a balance of the viscous drag and pressure force:

$$6\pi\mu r_p (U_f - U_p) = \frac{4\pi r_p^3}{3} \frac{dp}{dx}$$

where $U_f$ is the undisturbed speed of the fluid at the position of the particle centre and $U_p$ is the terminal speed of the particle.

Rearranging to find $U_p$, I obtain :

$$U_p=U_f + \frac{2p_0 r_p^2}{9L \mu}$$

Is this derivation flawed, or is it correct?

Comment: You are assuming in your calculations that the sphere reaches its terminal velocity before it reaches the end of the pipe. I'm also struggling to get my head around the result that at steady state the particle is moving faster than the fluid in the pipe. If the particle is moving faster than the fluid, it must have drag acting on it, so where is the force coming from that stops the particle slowing down to the speed of the fluid?

Comment: @Nick The pressure gradient in the fluid